# Using JAGS for bayesian parameter estimation

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, graphical-model

I am using [JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net/) in R to construct a probabilistic graph model and estimate the corresponding parameters. The models is described as follows:

```
model
{

   for (i in 1:N)

   {

       # sample the hidden variable 

       z[i]  ~ dbeta(alpha+0.01,beta)T(0,0.9999)

       # determined relation 
       lambda[i] <- z[i] * mu
       # conditional data likelihood 
       X[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
   }

       # prior probability 
       alpha ~ dgamma(0.1,0.0001)
       beta ~ dgamma(0.1,0.0001)
       mu ~ dgamma(0.1,0.0001)

}
```

where `X[1:N]` is the training samples, which are generated according to a Poisson distribution. The Poisson mean is also a random variable, which is denoted as `mu*z`. `z` is a hidden variable following a Beta distribution parametrized by variables `alpha` and `beta`. The parameters of this probabilistic model are `mu`, `alpha` and `beta`, and they follow Gamma distribution. I tested this model on a simulated set of data samples:

```
library('rjags')

N=5000

lambda=rbeta(N,0.2,0.3)*15 #alpha = 0.2,beta = 0.3 and mu = 15 

X=rpois(N,lambda)

jags = jags.model('poissontrunc.bugs',data = list('X' = X, 'N' = N),
                   n.chains = 4,
                   n.adapt = 1000)

mcmc.samples <- coda.samples(jags,
c('alpha', 'beta', 'mu'),
5000)

summary(mcmc.samples)
```

The MCMC-based parameter estimation results are as follows:

Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable, plus standard error of the mean:

```
         Mean      SD     Naive SE   Time-series SE

alpha  951.13,    35.0186,   0.247619,    9.72810   
beta  1013.24,   26.4553,   0.187068,     7.13232
mu      12.47,   0.3134,    0.002216,     0.08993
```

The sampling results give the right estimate of the true `mu` (12.47 vs. 15). However, for `alpha` and `beta`, it seems that the estimated values are severely biased (951.13 vs 0.2, 1013.24 vs 0.3). Even considering the variance of the sampling results, estimates for `alpha` and `beta` are still far from satisfaction. Is this a problem caused by any potential improper setting of the MCMC sampling, or perhaps MCMC is blocked within the local optimum region of a multi-modal conditional distribution in this case ?

Comment: Those priors aren't very good ones - going to $\infty$ near 0 in all three cases with means of 1000, if I recall the JAGS parameterization correctly - and I'd suggest rerunning the analysis with different ones. Try something along the lines of `alpha ~ dunif(0.001,2.0)` and same for beta, and `mu ~ dunif(1,30)` just to try out the code and see if it is the priors doing you in.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Indeed, dunif with this setting gives more consistent estimation results.